# Android-facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook

Can anyone tell me how to display facebook multifriend window in an android application?
I am new to android an I don't know how to do this.Could someone assist me..Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the [Facebook Android Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)?.

You can make use of the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to query for friends and for example display their photos in a GridView.

```
// get information about the currently logged in user
mAsyncRunner.request("me", new meRequestListener());

// get the posts made by the "platform" page
mAsyncRunner.request("platform/posts", new pageRequestListener());

// get the logged-in user's friends
mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new friendsRequestListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use Facebook sdk. full details can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sample